# Is it possible to request multiple scopes in ServiceM8 authorize GET request?

Tags: get

If yes, please provide proper syntax. 
I have already tried:

```
&scope[]=manage_jobs&scope[]=manage_customers
```

and:

```
&scope=manage_jobs,manage_customers
```

Answer (score 1):

To request multiple scopes you just need to separate them with a space. Because this is on a URL it will need to be percent-encoded.

`&scope=manage_jobs%20manage_customers`

Comment: Good answer, sidenote; you'd think the documentation would state this and *maybe* even give a single example of an implementation. :)